# Found '/prc0/0/615/igtime35545.7030001562' in my analytics top contents

Tags: google-analytics

Found that path in my analytics 'top content' pages. What is that? I googled but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a mal-formed img tag?  Can you look for the referrer in the logs?